# Use of IN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, list

I am using the (seemingly!) simple statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 130 IN (list)
```

My problem is, rows are:

- returned where table.list = 130, 120
- but NOT returned where table.list = 120, 130

In terms of behaviour, it looks as if IN only works if the value searched for is first in the list. This seems both illogical and wrong, but from bitter experience, I suspect the fault lies with me, rather than MySQL

Any assistance/insight much appreciated

Thanks in anticipation ...

Comment: at first, what is the type of `list`? Elaborate your question

Comment: list is VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass in a list as a parameter in MySQL (or in other databases as well).

You have basically two choices.  The first is to use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(130, list) > 0
```

The second is to "munge" the SQL string by including the list:

```
WHERE 130 in (". List .")
```

There are other options.  For instance, if the list starts out in the database, then a subquery or `JOIN` is the *right* solution.

EDIT:

You may have extra spaces in the list:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(130, REPLACE(list, ' ', '')) > 0
```

Comment: Apologies for earlier mistakenly submitted comment. SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET (130, list) > 0 produces the same result as the original query (SELECT * FROM table WHERE 130 IN (list)) and SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET (130, list) > 0 retrieves no rows. As to subqueries and joins, that's where I started, but all manner of variations have produced the same results (ie. only get a match if the search argument matches the first item in list). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, last comment should have read ...

SELECT * FROM table WHERE 130 IN (". list .")

retrieves no rows